# XNA Didn't add to my Visual C# Express

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, xna, visual-studio-express, visual-c#-express-2010

I installed VC# express and after that downloaded XNA Game Studio 4 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23714) and installed it. But I can't find any XNA template in my VC#. what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly, installing XNA will create a new shortcut called "XNA Game Studio" under either the Visual C# Express group or the XNA Game Studio group in the Start Menu. Use that.

If that isn't the case, then the project templates should show up in VC# under New -> Project -> Visual C# -> XNA Game Studio 4.0.

And if that isn't there either, your installation must be screwed up somehow. Uninstall XNA, uninstall VC#Express, reinstall VC#Express, reinstall XNA.

Comment: I re installed both of them but there were no XNA template again :(

Answer (score 0):

It is supposed to show up. Mine shows in the New Project list under Visual C# -> XNA Game Studio 4.0.

I am using VS Pro on this machine, but I have XNA installed on another machine with VS Express.

My advice would be to uninstall XNA and VS and reinstall from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the templates using Visual Studio addon gallery.
[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2010/10/05/10072040.aspx) is a page with a screenshot and explains the details.

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't XNA use it's own IDE? And I'm not sure VC# Express even supports XNA.

Comment: It doesn't use its own IDE and Express does support it.

Comment: Oh, my bad, was sure XNA had it's own version of VS Express.